# Payload encryption

Tags: crypto, transparent-data-encryption

We have a large request payload and customer would like to encrypt it before sending.Since SF **crypto class** have a limitation of 1MB , customer has asked us if it is possible to only encrypt the values of selected data elements in payload.

Eg If Request payload has Name, Age and SSN then it should get sent as below ie Name and SSN as encrypted:

**{
"Name": xxxxxxxx,
"Age": 35,
"SSN": xxxxxxxxxx
}**

Can we do this using the crypto methods?Is there any limitation in this approach?

Thanks,
MB

Comment: Can you provide info, on where did you get, that "Since SF has a limitation of 1MB"? If you are going to send a request from Apex to some endpoint, 6 MB for synchronous Apex or 12 MB for asynchronous Apex. 6 MB of the payload is in ASCII 6000000 symbols. Should not it be enough to encode the entire JSON payload?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi I should have been explicit.I was referring to InvalidParameterValue error exception which is thrown if the data is greater than 1 MB. For decryption, 1048608 bytes are allowed for the initialization vector header, plus any additional padding the encryption added to align to block size

Comment: thank you for providing additional info. Would you be able to add those additional details to the original question? with code snipped of what you are already trying so far and what exactly error do you have? That may help the community to help you.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi I have edited my main Q.I have not provided code snippet.It is an sample output which I have provided as an example and am trying to ask the community incase same is doable or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do take note of Oleksandr's comment about the total size of what you send being subject to governor limits: both the payload size and Apex heap size could get in the way and so block you.

But yes you will be able to encrypt individual text fields using e.g.:

```
 String s = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.encrypt(...));
```

with this best done before/as you build the JSON.